# Audio and Text file upload

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry new to SOF and my question might seem a bit vague.

Using android studio, i'd like to be able to upload an audio file and a text file generated from the audio file, to firebase. They are linked, however I can only upload the audio file to the firebase realtime-database. Is there any way to combine the .3gp file and the .txt file and upload them? Thanks.

---

Edited: This is my code so far. It's quite messy just trying to get the files together. Thanks.

---

private ImageButton recordButton;
    private TextView txtRec;

```
private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
private String mTextFileName = null;
private String mFileName = null;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "Record_Log";

private ProgressDialog mProgress;

private StorageReference mStorage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech);

    checkPermission();

    final TextView txtRec = findViewById(R.id.speechOutput);
    txtRec.setFocusable(false);
    final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

    recordButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/recorded_audio.3gp";
    mTextFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mTextFileName += "/recorded_text.txt";


    final Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());


    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            //getting all the matches
            ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                    .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            //displaying the first match
            if (matches != null)
                txtRec.setText(matches.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });

    recordButton.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
                    txtRec.setHint("You will see input here");
                    startRecording();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                    txtRec.setText("");
                    txtRec.setHint("Listening...");
                    stopRecording();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;

    uploadAudio();
}

private void uploadAudio() {

    mProgress.setMessage("Sending Audio...");

    final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Audio").child("new_audio.3gp");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName));
    filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            mProgress.dismiss();
            txtRec.setText("Sent");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! First of all, please read our guide how to ask questions! What is your code so far? What is the scpected output, and what happens instead?